# Multiple form validation issues on submit click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a multistep form which consists of three `fieldsets`.

Essentially when the user clicks the `next` button, the next `fieldset` will show.

**But I'm having two issues:**

---

**1.**

My function which checks if required fields in a `fieldset` are filled in is returning false, even when the `required` field is filled in.

The function is called `checkInputs()`. `#confirm` is the ID of my `next` button (full working demo will below):

```js
function checkInputs() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('fieldset').find('[required]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      isValid = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (isValid) {
    $('#confirm').prop('disabled', false)
  }
  return isValid;
}
```

---

**2.**

When a `required` field isn't filled in (doesn't have a value), I want to add a simple red border. To achieve this, I'm adding a class, on `next` click, to the `fieldset` and to any `input:required` with no val.

The issue I'm having with this are:

1. If I run the demo below (with no input) and click `next`, I'll see the following:

[image]

... this is correct. It shows which required inputs are not filled in and shows the error message. BUT, it also adds these classes to those `fieldsets` and `inputs` that are not visible yet (they will be visible on `next` click).

Of course you can't visually see this since my first issue prevents us from getting to the second fieldset, but in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vk0fsu4c/1/), if you just click `next` and then inpect the form, you can see that fieldssets with the comment `<!--fieldset 1-->` and `<!--fieldset 2-->` now have the class `.has-error` and so does it's inputs.

I only want the error classes to be added to the fieldset in view.

Also wondering if it's possible to add and remove classes dynamically? For example, if one of the `inputs` has an error (and therefore a red border), once the user fills it in, remove that class that assigns the red border (at the moment once it's filled in, you have to click `next` again for it to be removed).

---

Full demo:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
  var left, opacity, scale;
  var animating;

  /*************************************************/
  // CHECK IF FIELDS ARE FILLED IN BEFORE NEXT CLICK
  /**************************************************/

  function checkInputs() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('fieldset').find('[required]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
        isValid = false;
        return false;
      }
    });
    if (isValid) {
      $('#confirm').prop('disabled', false)
    }
    return isValid;
  }


  /***********************************************/
  // ONCLICK NEXT BUTTON, ANIMATE IN NEXT FIELDSET
  /***********************************************/

  $(".next").click(function() {

    checkInputs();

    if (checkInputs() == false) {
      
      console.log('required fields in this fieldset are not filled in.');
      
      
      // highlight invalid fields 
     $("fieldset").find(":required").filter(function() {
       if( $(this).val().length === 0 ) {
         $(this).addClass("error");
       } else {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
       }
   });

   // add class to fieldset on error
    $('fieldset input').each(function() {
       if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).parents('fieldset').addClass('has-error');
       }
          /* else{
                       $(this).parents('fieldset').removeClass('has-error');
                     } */

     });
      
      
    } else {
     console.log('all required fields are filled in, moving onto next fieldset');
      
     
     if (animating) return false;
      animating = true;
      current_fs = $(this).parent();
      next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

      next_fs.show();
      current_fs.animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
          scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
          left = (now * 50) + "%";
          opacity = 1 - now;
          current_fs.css({
            'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
            'position': 'absolute'
          });
          next_fs.css({
            'left': left,
            'opacity': opacity
          });
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function() {
          current_fs.hide();
          animating = false;
        },
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
      });
    } // else close
  });




});
```

```css
.form {
  min-height: 800px;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.form form#rsvpForm {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.form form#rsvpForm fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 60px 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
}
.form form#rsvpForm fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.form form#rsvpForm input,
.form form#rsvpForm textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}
.form form#rsvpForm input.error,
.form form#rsvpForm textarea.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.form form fieldset .error__message{
  display: none;
}

.form form fieldset.has-error .error__message{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js?ver=5.3.2'></script>

<div class="form" id="rsvp-form">

  <form id="rsvpForm" action="" method="post">

    <!-- fieldset 1 -->
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name*" required />
      <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address*" required></textarea>
      <input type="button" id="confirm" name="next" class="next" value="Next" />
      <div class="error__message"><p>Please complete all required fields.</p></div>
    </fieldset>
    
    <!-- fieldset 2 -->
    <fieldset>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*" required />
      <input type="button" id="confirm" name="next" class="next" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    

    <!-- fieldset 3 -->
    <fieldset>
      <textarea name="other" placeholder="Enter your note here ..." required></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>



  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you filter the input elements with an `opacity=1` in the `checkInputs()` function and the `.next` click event handler so only input elements are affected which are currently visible.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
  var left, opacity, scale;
  var animating;

  /*************************************************/
  // CHECK IF FIELDS ARE FILLED IN BEFORE NEXT CLICK
  /**************************************************/

  function checkInputs() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('fieldset').filter(function() {
      return $(this).css('opacity') == '1';
    }).find('[required]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
        isValid = false;
        return false;
      }
    });
    if (isValid) {
      $('#confirm').prop('disabled', false)
    }
    return isValid;
  }


  /***********************************************/
  // ONCLICK NEXT BUTTON, ANIMATE IN NEXT FIELDSET
  /***********************************************/

  $(".next").click(function() {

    checkInputs();

    if (checkInputs() == false) {

      console.log('required fields in this fieldset are not filled in.');


      // highlight invalid fields 
      $('fieldset').filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('opacity') == '1';
      }).find(":required").filter(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
          $(this).addClass("error");
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass("error");
        }
      });

      // add class to fieldset on error
      $('fieldset input').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
          $(this).parents('fieldset').addClass('has-error');
        }
        /* else{
                     $(this).parents('fieldset').removeClass('has-error');
                   } */

      });


    } else {
      console.log('all required fields are filled in, moving onto next fieldset');


      if (animating) return false;
      animating = true;
      current_fs = $(this).parent();
      next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

      next_fs.show();
      current_fs.animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
          scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
          left = (now * 50) + "%";
          opacity = 1 - now;
          current_fs.css({
            'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
            'position': 'absolute'
          });
          next_fs.css({
            'left': left,
            'opacity': opacity
          });
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function() {
          current_fs.hide();
          animating = false;
        },
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
      });
    } // else close
  });




});
```

```css
.form {
  min-height: 800px;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.form form#rsvpForm {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.form form#rsvpForm fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 60px 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
}
.form form#rsvpForm fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.form form#rsvpForm input,
.form form#rsvpForm textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}
.form form#rsvpForm input.error,
.form form#rsvpForm textarea.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.form form fieldset .error__message{
  display: none;
}

.form form fieldset.has-error .error__message{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js?ver=5.3.2'></script>

<div class="form" id="rsvp-form">

  <form id="rsvpForm" action="" method="post">

    <!-- fieldset 1 -->
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name*" required />
      <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address*" required></textarea>
      <input type="button" id="confirm" name="next" class="next" value="Next" />
      <div class="error__message"><p>Please complete all required fields.</p></div>
    </fieldset>
    
    <!-- fieldset 2 -->
    <fieldset>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*" required />
      <input type="button" id="confirm" name="next" class="next" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    

    <!-- fieldset 3 -->
    <fieldset>
      <textarea name="other" placeholder="Enter your note here ..." required></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>



  </form>

</div>
```